# dynamic configuration strings in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am new to SQL Server.

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL Server 2012 through my node js express application in VS 2012 with the following connection string.

```
var config = "Server={IPv4 add};Database=Dbname;Uid=domain\\username;Pwd=password";
```

I want to take in the values of username & password dynamically through a HTML form.

I store the entries in variables 'uid' & 'pwd' through app.post() of express and when I do this

```
 var config = '"Server={IPv4 add};Database=Dbname;Uid=domain\\' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pwd+'"';
```

it throws an error in the console saying

```
Invalid connection String
```

and when I do this (removing " ")

```
'Server={IPv4 add};Database=Dbname;Uid=domain\\' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pwd;
```

The error is

```
Untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication
```

I have been querying MySQL this way all the time. I tried this because I thought SQL Server might work the same way. Please tell me from where can I read about this & make it work.

Thank you

EDIT1 : I am using Windows authentication

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But in my office, I want only people who are authenticated to use the remote server to use it

Comment: I already have an existing system where people are supposed to login, If they have been granted access in the directory they can access data, else, they cannot. I have to replace it using node js

Comment: Please remove `"`. So `= '"Server...` become `= 'Server...`

Comment: 'Server={IPv4 add};Database=Dbname;Uid=domain\\' + uid + ';Pwd=' + pwd;  throws an error: Untrusted domain & cannot be used with Windows authentication

Comment: Please don't publish confidential data. Update your question with this message.

Comment: am sry..got added while i was still typing.. & this errors has usually occured to me when it cant match the credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. It was simply because of the asynchronous running, the config statement ran before the credentials were being entered. Silly mistake. Sorry for bothering you